# Lost JSF beginner: Linux, Geronimo and tag library

Tags: linux, jsf, tomcat, geronimo

I use Geronimo with J2EE 5 and Tomcat 6 and I'm trying to create one simple page using JSF. I put the tag library files `myfaces_core.tld` and `myfaces_html.tld` in `WEB-INF` and it works, but just on Windows. Under Linux I got `IOException` with *an unknown reason* when I was deploying the WAR. To remove the two tag library files made the deploy possible. But then I got an error when I was opening the page in browser. It was missing the file `WEB-INF/myfaces_html.tld`, which is specified in the header of JSP file. In examples for MyFaces there is used not MyFaces TLD, but common Sun Java TLD. I have overwritten the URI `WEB-INF/myfaces_html.tld` to `http://java.sun.com/jsf/html` ant now I'm getting the error *The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsf/html cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application*.

I'm lost now. Must I or must I not put the tag library description files into my WAR to use JSF components? These files are already contained in MyFaces JARs in Geronimo Container, aren't? The container must have the same behavior regardless to platform or it needn't? What shall I do to create my simple application really platform independent?

Answer (score 1):

You should **not** be extracting JAR files of 3rd party tag libraries and placing its loose TLD files in the `/WEB-INF` folder. The TLD files should be kept in the JAR files where they originate and the JAR files should be untouched and just be dropped in the runtime classpath. Whatever book/tutorial/forum is suggesting otherwise should be blacklisted.

Cleanup your project structure to get rid of those loose TLD files and undo every change related to this, for sure also in the `web.xml`, if any.

Your `/WEB-INF/lib` folder should contain just two files in order to get JSF to run on Tomcat 6: one file representing the abstract API and other representing the concrete implementation. As you've apparently chosen to use MyFaces, it'll be those two JAR files (probably with a version number at end of filename, that depends):

- myfaces-api.jar
- myfaces-impl.jar

Drop them in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder which is part of the webapp's default runtime classpath. That's all. Next step would be declaring and mapping the `FacesServlet` in your webapp's `web.xml`.

Ensure that you're reading the proper book/tutorial.

Comment: It seems something is wrong with the JSF-servlet on Linux. At Windows it works. Geronimo already contains the JSF implementation (MyFaces). To remove the TLD files form the `WEB-INF` directory and update the URIs of the HTML and the Core libraries according to the (MyFaces tutorial) JSF standard (change URIs to `http://java.sun.com/jsf/html` and `http://java.sun.com/jsf/html`) is just a little correction not having any effect. It works under Windows and not under Linux anyway. The _unknown reason_ is most likely somewhere in the Geronimo container on Linux, in the JSF servlet.

Comment: If the container already ships with JSF, you actually shouldn't include any in the webapp, or you would need to specify a container-specific config file or context param which instructs the container to **not** load container-bundled JSF libraries (this is at least true for JBoss AS, Glassfish, etc).